# Where do I place a decoupling capacitor when the power supply is intermittent?

Tags: infrared, decoupling-capacitor

I'm building a low power obstacle detector.
I have an infrared LED and a IR photoresistor wired up to a [BLE Nano](http://redbearlab.com/blenano/) (a tiny bluetooth IC) running off a small 3v coin battery.

[image: circuit diagram]

My code basically does this.

```
digital-out 2 ON (powers the photoresistor)
take a reading from analog-in 1 (reading 1)
digital-out 1 ON (turns on the IR LED)
take a reading from analog-in 1 (reading 2)
digital-out 1 OFF
digital-out 2 OFF
```

if `reading 1` and `reading 2` are different I know there is something reflecting back IR.

The problem I'm having is that `reading 2` seems to be picking up noise and often reports a different value to `reading 1` (even when I know no IR has been detected). I believe this effect grows as the battery drains.

I would like to place a decoupling capacitor either on the LED circuit, the photoresistor circuit, or both. 
Because I want this to be as low powered as possible I'd rather not have current constantly going though the photoresistor as most of the time I will not be taking readings. I can't seem to figure out where I would place those capacitors or even if this is the correct solution.

Any help (even if it's a simple "this can't be done") much appreciated.

Comment: How much of a difference do you see and how does this value compare to the noise/accuracy spec of the ADC in your device?

Comment: The difference is very low but relatively consistent. I'm sure it's a voltage drop from turning on the LED rather than just random noise.

Comment: You need to use a threshold in your software.  Don't check just for a difference.  Check for a difference greater than some percentage of the first value.  Say the first reads 500.  Using a 10% threshold, you would assume something is reflecting if the second reading is over 550.  Also, you will probably need to wait a short period after turning on the LED before you make a measurement.  Some milliseconds (may 10 or 20) should help.  Or, average several readings from analaog in.

Comment: If turning on the LED is causing a voltage drop to the nano, then your LED series resistor is too small and you are drawing too much current from your coin cell.  A large capacitor in parallel to the coin cell wil probably help, but only if you keep the on time of the LED short (milliseconds.)

Comment: Are you really using a LDR (light-dependent-resistor) as you've labeled it or is that a photodiode as your schematic symbol implies? What does your device's ADC use for its reference (fixed or Vcc)? Are you sure there's no possible light path between the emitter & detector except for the near reflection you're looking for?

Comment: @JRE This is what I've been doing but it seems to change as the battery drains. Ultimately if no other solution can be found this is what I'll have to do and just accept the possibility of a false positive. I hadn't thought of a cap at the battery level that might be something to try.

Comment: @brhans I may of messed up the schematic. I'm using [these things](http://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/sfe-infrared-emitter-detector.html)

I've spent a lot of time trying to make sure no IR is getting though so I'm pretty sure it's not that but it may be a slim possibility

Comment: JRE's answer about thresholds is the right one - the value will drift a bit for all sorts of reasons, so you should only register a positive if the values are different "enough". You'll have to determine your own value of "enough".